# join tables for multiple database tables does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

join tables for multiple database tables does not work in below code

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :cities_db
  self.table_name_prefix = "cities_db."
  has_many :clients
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  # default connection
  belongs_to :city
  self.table_name = "client"

  def self.with_cities
    joins(:city)
  end
end

Client.with_cities # returns ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'cities_db.clients' doesn't exist: SELECT `city_db`.`cities`.* FROM `cities_db`.`cities` INNER JOIN `clients` ON `clients`.`city_id` = `cities_db`.`cities`.`id`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

root cause: setting table_name does not set table_name_prefix

Client.with_cities is run in context of :cities_db connection. To fix it change Client.rb

```
self.table_name = "client"
```

to

```
self.table_name = "#{self.connection.current_database}.client"
```